# Protege 5 first ontology

Tags: dependencies, ontology, protege

i am a beginner to ontologies and just fail to define it right.

what are my constraints:
i have a class objects with subclasses wall, window ...
i have a class properties with ? subclasses or individuals for properties like name, color ...
i have defined information requests as phases.

my task now is to define an onthology for these relations:

for a "wall" the property called "name" has to be satisfied at "time" from "engineer"
for a "window" the property called "name" has to be satisfied at "other time" from "architect"

my question now: shall properties like "name" be individuals or subclasses?
how do i connect the "time" constraint depending on my subclass?

thank you?

OK trying to be more precise:

```
Class: Object
Class: Wall
  SubClassOf: Object

Class: Window
  SubClassOf: Object

Class: Properties
Class: Name
  SubClassOf: Properties

Class: Color
  SubClassOf: Properties

Class: Phases
Class: Start
  SubClassOf: Phases

Class: End
  SubClassOf: Phases
```

my question is how to relate "Name" to "Start" if in relation with a "Wall"

something like:
if "Wall":"Name":"Start" 
if "Window":"Name":"End"

does that make sense?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "for a "wall" the property called "name" has to be satisfied at "time" from "engineer" for a "window" the property called "name" has to be satisfied at "other time" from "architect"". Please edit your question to explain this better.

Comment: You have to have an `ObjectProperty` to relate individuals of the `Name` class to individuals of the `Start` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find value in going through the [Pizza ontology tutorial](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf).

For complete information on translating UML class diagrams to OWL 2 you can go [here](https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/uml-class-diagram-to-owl-and-sroiq-reference.pdf).

As a brief example, to state Wall is a subclass of Object in Protege you need to state:

```
Class: Object
Class: Wall
   SubClassOf: Object
```

To state that a wall has a specific colour, in Protege you can define the following:

```
Class: Colour
  EquivalentTo: {Green, Amber, Red}
Individual: Green
  Types: Colour
Individual: Amber
  Types: Colour
Individual: Red
  Types: Colour
DifferentIndividuals: Green, Amber, Red

ObjectProperty: hasColour
  Domain: Wall
  Range: Colour

Class: Wall
  SubClassOf: hasColour some Thing
```